# One-liner? Move lines after 1st line not matching pattern after one that does

Tags: command-line, search

I’m exploring Vim’s capabilities and somehow stumbled upon this task. It’s constructed, but I’m curious:
Is there a one-liner colon command that can

1. find the first line that matches a pattern p (say, begins with „bla“)
2. find the first line after this line that doesn’t match p and
3. move lines 4-5 after the line found in 2.?

The order of 1.-3. doesn’t matter for purposes of execution, that’s just to explain what I’m thinking of achieving.

Thanks guys! Vim is so great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
:/\(bla[^\n]*\)\+\zs/;4,5m.
```

which finds multiple (`+`) occurrences of `bla` followed by new line characters (`[^\n]`), then place the cursor (`;`) where we set our start of match (`\zs`) and move our range of lines (`4,5`) at the current cursor position. See: `:help :/`.

To insert lines at the end of the whole pattern (not after first line of match), change `bla[^\n]` into `\nbla`, e.g.:

```
:/\(\nbla\)\+\zs/;4,5m.
```

Instead of current cursor position (`.`), you can also use variety of different addresses to move the lines into, like `\/` (the next line where the previously used search pattern matches or other addresses; see `:help {address}`).

Comment: I think this should have a `[^\n]*` inserted after the `bla`, since OP said "begins with" bla, not "only contains" bla.

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks, probably I misunderstood 2. step, I've expanded my answer based on your advice. Hope that's clearer now.

Comment: Yep.  I like this approach because it doesn't require the regex be typed in twice.

Comment: Having the pattern just once is a plus. I got it working after what looks like correcting a misunderstanding, because bla is just the start of the line. `/\(\nbla.*\)\+\zs/;4,5m.`

Comment: I also like learning that I can move the cursor with `;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
:/^bla/,/^\(bla\)\@!/;4,5 m .
```

Here `:/^bla/,/^\(bla\)\@!/;` searches for the first line that begins with `bla`, then finds the next line that does not begin with `bla` and puts the cursor there (with `;`). The next part, `4,5 m .` then moves lines 4 and 5 to the cursor position `.`.

Note that this requires well thought out regexps, and I was not able to find a way to reuse the first regexp in the second.

Comment: What is your thinking in using \@! here? I admit I don't know what this is supposed to do, but it's interesting!

Comment: `\@!` is used to prevent a match of the previous atom, that is, it matches with zero width if the previous part does not match.

Comment: To make it more clear: `/^\(bla\)\@!/` matches any line that does NOT start with `bla`. This is done with the `\@!` multi. I find the list in `:h pattern-overview` very good to show the difference between the different patterns.